# Accessing POST wcf services from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, wcf, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I have been given url of an asp.net wcf service page which accepts few parameters as POST. But I am getting error code 400 when I try to access it.
url:

> http://domain.w04.wh-2.com/IBServiceHost/IBService.svc/AddTask

I am also told to post json as below

```
{  
     "TaskId":"23",  
     "TaskDate":"6/27/2013",  
     "TaskDesc":"Test task",  
     "TaskName":"TestName",  
     "TaskStatus":true,  
     "ProjectId":"24",  
      "DbState":"Added"  
}
```

My code to access the service:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.w04.wh-2.com"]];
        client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
        NSMutableURLRequest *request =
        [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/IBServiceHost/IBService.svc/AddTask" parameters:dictTask];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
        [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
         {
             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"]);
             NSLog(@"Code: %@", [[[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"] valueForKeyPath:@"Code"] stringValue]);
             NSLog(@"FaultString: %@", [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"] valueForKeyPath:@"FaultString"]);
         }
                                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
         {
             NSLog(@"request %@",request);
             NSLog(@"response %@",response);
             NSLog(@"error %@",error);
             NSLog(@"error opening connection");
         }];
        [operation start];
```

Comment: The parameters you are sending are most likely incorrect, where are they defined in the code?

Comment: I have already mentioned the dictionary that I am sending along with the request.

Comment: The easiest way is to inspect your raw request that is generated from your code when it make a call using Fiddler and then checking if the JSON is as expected.

Comment: Hi Pankaj could you resolve the issue. I am facing the same problem